# Unable to execute a custom directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a simple custom directive, but it is constantly throwing me an error. I have included my sample code in the below jsFiddle link. Can anyone help me with where exactly I went wrong.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/sridharspeaks/65vnj4dz/][1]
```

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: you link is broken

Comment: I was able to open it

Comment: Thank you Tamas. I am unable to set the link properly in the editor and I am trying for it. People are too quick and happy to downmark a question rather actually trying to solve a real question. I will continue to edit it to make it as a proper link.

Answer (score 1):

this is fixed plunker :

http://plnkr.co/edit/KTFFLc0QdmunQ4i8AT8o?p=preview

i think there is a problem with

1. the case of your directive and controller name ( i put all to lower case, don't have too much time sorry)
2. you didn't use `ng-controller="mycontainercontroller"` to tell angular with controller to use
3. don't inject $scope on directive only in controller's directive :

html :

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="mycontainercontroller">
     <mycontainer></mycontainer>
  </div>
</body>
```

and JS :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('mycontainer', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'mycontainercontroller',
    template: '<div><input ng-model="container"></div><div>output : {{container}}</div>'
  }
}).controller('mycontainercontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.container = 123;
}]) ;
```

Comment: Alainlb, thank you for your help. I believe ng-controller in html is not required, since it is embeded with custom directive already.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. One is with the fiddle, the script must run before window load, so set the following:

[image]

Second, don't inject `$scope` into the directive. You only have access to the directive scope in the `link` function.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65vnj4dz/5/

Comment: Awesome. Though from the below answer I could able to check it as working in plunkr, I am unable to execute it in jsFiddle. Thanks for showing this out.